# How to add a label below images in a row in flutter and to add a card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code and here I just want to know how to add text below the images.
 Just let me know, please?

```
child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/cat.jpg',
                    ),
                    Text('cat')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
                    Text('cat')
                  ],

                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
                    Text('cat')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ]);
      },
    )
```

Comment: Thank you sir and yes maybe I will be having problem with flutter in future is there any platform I cn connect with you?

Comment: keep asking on stackoverflow and you will get the best answers

Answer (score 3):

```
Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset('assets/img.jpg'),
            ),
            Text('My Image'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

You can put this code row or as you want. You can also put some padding to arrange the text image. If you want constant height and weight put this into a Container Widget and specify the height and weight. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the image in a Column/Stack

```
child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
                Text('Some text')
              ],)
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
                Text('Some text')
              ],)
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
                Text('Some text')
              ],)
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: it didn't worked. You cant use that 'Text' in Image.asset. It is showing "Too many positional arguments 1 expected 2 found".

Comment: I have a typo, I’ll change it. I missed a bracket

Comment: yeah there are typos " children: <Widget> not <Widgets> and then inside Image brackets . and it is because it is one line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a line of text below the images at once

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg',
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
   Text("Your text here"),
]), // column widget ends here
```

If you want to add text below each image then
change your Expanded widget with this.

```
Expanded(
   child: Column(
       children : <Widget>[
         Image.asset('assets/cat.jpg'),
         Text("your text here")
       ] 
   )
),
```

else create a function to return a widget as it seems you have plenty of widgets of that kind

```
Widget getWidget(imagePath, text){
   return Expanded(
      child: Column(
          children : <Widget>[
            Image.asset(imagePath),
            Text(text)
          ] 
       )
     )
}
```

and then use this

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        getWidget('assets/cat.jpg','your text here'),
        getWidget('assets/cat.jpg','your text here'),
        getWidget('assets/cat.jpg','your text here'),
      ],
    ),
]),
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I will make the round borders to the images

Comment: you can wrap your image under widget `ClipRRect()`, and please do let me know if my answer helped you.

Comment: yeah, it helped using ClipRRect() but that round is not as same as I get when I use border-radius. When I am increasing values to get more circular corners I am getting sides to get circular not edges.